# Quando é que tenho de cancelar a assinatura(unsubscribe) de eventos?

Tags: c#, eventos

Uma [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4172809/2556111) sobre o mesmo tema tem uma [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4172848/2556111) que diz:

> You don't have to desubscribe from an event when the instance that is subscribing has the same scope as the instance that is being subscribed to.

Tradução livre:

> Não é necessário "*cancelar a assinatura"* de um evento quando o **objecto subscrito** e o **objecto subscritor** têm o mesmo tempo de vida.
>
> Ex: O objecto A(subscritor) cria o objecto B(subscrito), A subscreve um evento de B.

Quanto a isto não tenho qualquer dúvida. É a situação mais frequente, quando se utiliza eventos.
A minha dificuldade está em identificar uma situação que não seja essa.

O que peço é um exemplo/explicação de quando o *"cancelar a assinatura"* de eventos é necessária.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O contrário da [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172809/should-i-unsubscribe-from-events/4172848#4172848) é o cenário em que vai ser necessário proceder ao cancelamento da assinatura, ou seja, quando os tempos de vida dos objectos forem diferentes.

Tome o exemplo de um evento estático:

```
public static class MyStaticClass
{
    public static event OnMyEvent MyEvent;
}
```

E uma instância que subscreve esse evento:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass
    {
        MyStaticClass.MyEvent += ...
    }
}
```

Neste caso, o tempo de vida dos objectos é claramente diferente. Assim é necessário proceder ao cancelamento da assinatura do evento quando o objecto instanciado deixar de ser necessário, caso contrário, o evento estático, como contêm uma referência para o objecto instanciado, vai impedir que este seja recolhido pelo `GC`.